# I can't import pandas in jupyter notebook (Python 3 in anaconda)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have Anaconda installed on my laptop. I opened my windows command prompt and went ahead with typing `jupyter notebook` and it opened successfully in the browser. But when I tried to type in `Import pandas as pd` it gave me an error message like this:

```
 ` File "<ipython-input-3-cd3275bba7c6>", line 1
Import sys
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
```

The Kernel is Python 3, there is no other option there. 
I tried updating the Anaconda navigator and shut everything down before trying again, but it still won't work.

I suspected it had something to do with having both Python in my machine and Anaconda? 
I read that other people that have the same problem tried uninstalling and installing pandas again, or changing the environment path (?). Unfortunately I am not quite sure how I do any of them as I am very new in learning Python.

Can someone give me some directions as to how this should be done?

PS: Others say that there should be only one Python, either Python or Anaconda in the machine. So which one is better and which one should be gotten rid of, if needed?

All I want is to practice Python for a udemy class I am taking and I am stuck with the problem already.

Comment: Why is I in capital in the Import statement?

Comment: This is not a conflict between Python interpreters. The error you show is a syntax error, your post shows capitalized `Import`.
Use `import` and you should be past this error.

Comment: Oh my, you're right! I had no idea that makes a very big difference!! Thank you so much you guys! Seems like I still have a long way to go to master Python :p